# Use special characters in the CSS content

Tags: css, unicode, special-characters

Which is the *correct* way of using it? Unicode or just the character itself, although the results seem to be the same.

```css
h1:before {
    content: "\263A";
}
h1:after {
    content: "☺";
}
```

```html
<h1>Smile</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results are the same *if* the character encoding of the file containing this code has been appropriately declared. See the W3C page [Character encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset) and the linked resources, but note that the advice “Try to avoid using the byte-order mark in UTF-8” is not correct. Using the byte order mark (BOM) adds extra protection; advice to the contrary is either outdated or relates to PHP, which is a different issue. So basically you should save your CSS file as UTF-8 encoded *with BOM*.

Using references like `"\263A"` avoids the character encoding issue, at the cost of source readability. The rest is rather opinion-based.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation I couldn't find it anywhere.